# what happend when Android enters in sleep/standby with html5 geolocation

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Im thinking in making a dispatcher-like web in php for use in android phones. So I need to upload the current location to a server in a x interval of time.
I have the idea and code to start working on it, my question is:

Someone have the browser open on their phone, the web sents via ajax in a presetted interval its location to the server and gets some items back to a google map. But what will the phone do when the screen goes off (sleeps/standby mode). It will keep posting the location? It will post it using antennas (A-GPS) instead of GPS?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, and when de device goes on standby it stops sending data.

Comment: Thanks, that a shame, I'll need to keep the phone awake if I want to use it for geolocation.